# Problom in Django REST Framework IsAdminUser permission class

Tags: django-rest-framework

This permission return True for staff_user's, what is problem ?

```
class IsAdminUser(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to admin users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)
```

Comment: Admin users and staff users are not the same...

Comment: this is django rest framework permission, Isn't it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use built in IsAdmin permission from rest_framework permissions

example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser
```

if you are using generics views, an example of how to use this permission is add a permission_classes where you define the queryset or serializer_class

```
serializer_class = ModelSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

or if you are using functional api views, u can first import

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes as perm
```

and then before defining the function add this

```
@api_view(['GET']
@perm([IsAdminUser])
def functionalApiView(request):
    ...
```

Comment: ```class IsAdminUser(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to admin users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)
``` this is built in IsAdminUser permission, and this is wrong :)

Comment: unless the task you are trying to accomplish is allowing admins some permissions,